# Map ifPresent function

Tags: java, dictionary, lambda, java-8

How can I execute a function on a value of a map only if it is present, without making any changes to the map? I want to do this using the 'Java 8' declarative style, comparable to `Optional.ifPresent()`.

My use case is as follows:

I receive updates (new or deleted) to objects in part, I want to register these updates with their parent. For bookkeeping I have the following:

```
Map<ParentId, Parent> parents = ...
```

When receiving a new child I do the following:

```
parents.computeIfAbsent(child.getParentId(), k -> new Parent()).addChild(child));
```

However for removing I can't find the declarative function. Straight forward I would implement this as:

```
if(parents.containsKey(child.getParentId())
{
     parents.get(child.getParentId()).removeChild(child);
}
```

Or I could wrap the value in an `Optional`:

```
Optional.ofNullable(parents.get(child.getParentId()).ifPresent(p -> p.removeChild(child));
```

Note that Parent is not a simple list, it contains more than just children. So the following doesn't work (because `removeChild()` doesn't return a `Parent`):

```
parents.computeIfPresent(child.getParentId(), (k, v) -> v.removeChild());
```

How can I do this, or is there no equivalent to `Optional.ifPresent()`?

Comment: They way with optional is probably the easiest approach and the cleanest i can think of

Comment: What happens when the parent ends up with no children? Do you need to remove that parent from the map as well, or is it OK if the parent remains with no children?

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner Nothing for this example (in my case, because there also is other data that must be saved).

Answer (score 7):

I think your `Optional` solution looks ok, but for

> the following doesn't work (because removeChild() doesn't return a Parent):
>   `parents.computeIfPresent(child.getParentId(), (k, v) -> v.removeChild());`

you could extend the lambda to

```
parents.computeIfPresent(child.getParentId(), (k, v) -> { v.removeChild(); return v; });
```

I'd say the straight-forward way is clearest in this case though, I'd go with that.

Comment: It’s worth noting that even if this `computeIfPresent` use effectively does not change the map, immutable maps might reject it with an `UnsupportedOperationException` without even checking whether the function would evaluate to a new value.

Answer (score 1):

If there are no side effects to creating an unnecessary parent, and no exception is thrown by removing an absent child, you could use:

```
parents.getOrDefault(child.getParentId(), new Parent()).removeChild(child);
```

Comment: @Lino, this will add the value to the map if it was not present.